# Ionic 5 Harware Back Button only refresh the home page (without exiting the app)

Tags: angular, refresh, hardware, exit, ionic5

I am a bit new to mobile developments and in my app (Ionic 5, Angular 13, Android 9) I want to exit the app on touch of hardware back button (Best is at the home page). However, it only refresh the home page without exiting the app. I read several tutorials found on the internet including the following.

[ionic - back button exit app not working in Ionic 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182359/ionic-back-button-exit-app-not-working-in-ionic-5)

But non of them seems helping me. Given below is my app.component.ts. What have I missed? Please help me. Thank you so much.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, IonRouterOutlet, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

@ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, { static : true }) routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private location: Location,
    private alertController: AlertController

  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  backButtonEvent(){
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10,()=>{
      if (!this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()){
        this.backButtonAlert();
      } else {
        this.location.back();
      }
    })
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.backButtonEvent();
    });
  }

  async backButtonAlert(){
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: "Do you want to close the app?",
      buttons: [{
        text: "Cancel",
        role: "Cancel"
      },{
        text: "Close",
        handler: ()=>{
          navigator['app'].exitApp();
        }
      }]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with these changes:

```
backButtonEvent(){
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, async ()=>{
        if (!this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()){
            this.backButtonAlert();
        } 
        else {
            this.location.back();
        }
    })
}
```

Changes: `priority` lowered to 1 and added `async` to the function.

**Another option to try, if `canGoBack` is causing issues:**

Import Router:
`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Put it in constructor:
`private readonly router: Router`

```
backButtonEvent(){
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, async ()=>{
    // put yourMainPage name here, the one where hardware backbutton
    // will have to exit the app
    if (this.router.url === '/yourMainPage') {
        this.backButtonAlert();
    }
    else { // if the user is on other page, he'll just go to previous
        window.history.back();
    }
}
```

And in `backButtonAlert` try both `navigator['app'].exitApp();` and `this.platform.exitApp();` and see if one would work.

Comment: Thank you so much Misha. But that also not working. Is there anything I should do in home page? The Interesting thing is just after the app started the app exits by hardware back. But when I touch the home screen (just a single touch without doing anything) this bug emerges.

Comment: I've edited an answer with another option, if canGoBack is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks Misha. There were several things. In this.platform.exitApp(); there is an error saying that "Property 'exitApp' does not exist on type 'Platform'. I searched the internet for the issue but I could not find anything clear. And the other interesting thing is that I was testing it with Android 10 and later I found app is exiting with Android 7 without alert. (In both Android versions the alert/verification does not popup). In Android 10 something is refreshing the home page without exiting the app.

Comment: Gayath I'm facing the same issue .. Have you found out any solution? Please clarify.